# Magento: Creating Static pages with no FTP access

Tags: magento

I need to create several static pages within a Magento webstore. The pages share the same look and feel, but different content, so I would need a common CSS for them. Also, they have a common navigation that links between them.

An example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0e5qn4d0fc2xdwx/magento-info-template-new.jpg?dl=0

Can I do that ONLY through Magento Admin Panel? My website is hosted as SAAS solution, and I don't have cPanel, or FTP access.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a static block using magento admin panel.

For this, please go to CMS> Static Blocks> Add New Block.
Here, fill the required information like Block Title, Identifier, Store View, status, content.

In the "content" your all html/css part will go.

After that if you want to assign this to the page then you need to use it like

{{widget type="cms/widget_block" template="cms/widget/static_block/default.phtml" block_id="Identifier name"}}

Using this, you will be able to show this static block on this page for frontend.

Cheers!!

Comment: thanks. what about the css? Can I include an external stylesheet and upload that through admin? Internal stylesheet? Am I forced to use inline CSS?

Comment: You can use the css in the static block in <style></style> tag.
Here, you cannot include any external css (stylesheet) file.

Comment: If this is worked for you? then please accept this as "answer"/voteup so that other users use this as usefull answer.